# Abandoned memory after Modal segue with StoryBoard and ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, storyboard, segue, abandoned-memory

I have a problem with growing memory using StoryBoard.
I use modal segues to get to the next or prev. Viewcontroller.

[Sample UIStoryBoard](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/955031/segue1.png)
When i run Instruments i can see the Viewcontrollers never gets out of the memory.
So they are added and added each segue.

[Instruments Allocations](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/955031/segue2.png)

How can i get this Viewcontroller out of the memory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using modal segue to go back to the previous scene. Then , when every segue is performing there are new allocations ...

Just use this method to go back previous scene:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and delete the second modal segue that you use for go backing .